# Hibernate column value from database

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I faced with situation when I need save\update entity's field (persistent field that represent column) using value from Oracle's function (namely using **select user from dual**). I tried to use @Formula but it didn't work for me even in conjunction with @Pre*** methods.
Could someone please assist me with this question?